# Perl EPIC Not recognising installed CPAN modules

Tags: eclipse, perl, cpan

Eclipse on a mac, was working fine adding new modules until I Installed `Text::CSV_XS` which Eclips doesn't recognise as added to `@INC` For instance

```
use strict;
use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;

SOAP::Transport::HTTP::CGI->dispatch_to('C2FService')->handle;

BEGIN {

    package C2FService;
    use vars qw(@ISA);
    @ISA = qw(Exporter SOAP::Server::Parameters);
    use SOAP::Lite;

    sub c2f {
        my $self     = shift;
        my $envelope = pop;
        my $temp     = $envelope->dataof("//c2f/temperature");
        return SOAP::Data->name(
            'convertedTemp' => ( ( ( 9 / 5 ) * ( $temp->value ) ) + 32 ) );
    }
}
```

`use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;` is marked as error if I comment it out `use SOAP::Lite;` is in turn marked as an error, not found etc the usual if a module is not installed. 
Both are installed with CPAN and

```
$ perl -c soap-test.pl 
post-code-check.pl syntax OK
```

Perl is fine CPAN tests are all pass, the code works, only EPIC lags behind.

```
$ pwd && ls 
/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.4/SOAP
Client.pod      Lite            Server.pod
Constants.pm        Lite.pm         Test.pm
Data.pod        Packager.pm     Trace.pod
Deserializer.pod    SOM.pod         Transport
Fault.pod       Schema.pod      Transport.pod
Header.pod      Serializer.pod      Utils.pod
```

And if I have `use` errors in the start of my files the rest of the source is not error checked..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix this by adding all the paths I found on my system to the project include path manually through `(click in the source of your project) > Project > Properties` 
Go to the root directory of your project and open the `.includepath` file and make sure there are no trailing spaces after the paths and the closing quotes:

`<includepathentry path="/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.4 " />` which some of my entries had even though I just copy pasted them in Eclipse's GUI from the terminal there's no way there could've been a trailing space.

After all of these of course clean projects from the same `Project` menu.

Comment: I'm having this same problem but I don't have a .includepath file on the root of my Perl project. Also I ignore where cpan installs modules so to add the path...

Comment: You can create one by focusing in the project (click on a src file in the proj explorer) then from the menus Project > Properties > "Perl Include Path" when you change that it should make a file. BTW you may not see it, hidden, starts with `.`

Answer (score 1):

Just adding the step-by-step for including modules in Eclipse Perl EPIC *(with a few extra notes)*:

1. Right click your project > Properties > Perl Include Path
2. Enter or browse for the path you want to include

   *In case your folder or files have spaces, make sure to surround the include path with double quotes*
3. Pre-pend your path with `${project_loc}/` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11693128/2434565)

   i.e. `${project_loc}"/path/to/some module"` or `"${project_loc}/path/to/some module"`
4. Click 'Add to List' > Ok.
5. Restart Eclipse